# Irq routines Causing General Protection Fault

Tags: c, assembly, kernel

I am getting continuous GPF after installing the irqs with PIT and enabling interrupts by sti.

This is the IRQ handler code in the  :

```
  void irq_handler(struct regs *r)
  {   
  void (*handler)(struct regs *r);

  handler = irq_routines[r->int_no - 32];
  if (handler)
    handler(r);

  if (r->int_no >= 40)
  {
    outportb(0xA0, 0x20);
  }

  outportb(0x20, 0x20);
  }
```

irq_rountine is an array of function pointers. I believe my IDT implementations(structures) are correct and setting the IRQs by **idt_set_gate(32, (unsigned)irq0, 0x08, 0x8E);**.

IRQ common handler code in main.asm :

```
 irq_common_stub:
 pusha
 push %ds
 push %es
 push %fs
 push %gs
 mov $0x10, %ax
 mov %ax, %ds
 mov %ax, %es
 mov %ax, %fs
 mov %ax, %gs
 mov %esp, %eax
 push %eax
 mov $irq_handler, %eax
 call *%eax
 pop %eax
 pop %gs
 pop %fs
 pop %es
 pop %ds
 popa
 add $0x8, %esp
 iret
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `add $0x8, %esp` at the bottom? There's no corresponding push, and IRQs don't push anything extra on the stack when they trigger.

Comment: Just wanted to ask the same. Look s strange IMO.

Comment: I am pushing Error code and IDT number for IRQs to the stack (In the IRq0-15 routines) Like following : 

`irq4:
    cli
    push  $0x0
    push  $36
    jmp irq_common_stub`

`Add $0x08, %esp` is cleaning up the error code and ISR number.

Comment: I don't know but IRQs are working as expected when i tried to run qemu with the binary created like `qemu-system-i386 -kernel myos.bin`. 

I was running the Kernel previously by `qemu-system-i386 -cdrom myos.iso`. iso file is created with grub-mrescue utility.

Comment: That is strange because the same thing works for me.

Comment: Maybe it is connected with grub?